# Certificate error while using sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, 32-bit

I [tried asking this on askubuntu but haven't found an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664680/certificate-error-while-using-sudo-apt-get-update).

I installed Ubuntu Server 32-bit 14.04 on an old machine, and I tried to run `sudo apt-get update` but it's followed by this error message:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release 
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources    
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources    
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources    
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources    
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources 
    server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none 
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I attempted the following solutions:

1. Update dns server to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`
2. `sudo update-ca-certificates`

   ```
    Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
    Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
    done.
    done.
   ```
3. I made sure it's not being done under proxy connection.

**sources.list**

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta i386 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta i386 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: please post your /etc/apt/sources.list
`http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/source/Sources` gives me 404

Comment: This is a fresh new installation so whatever is in sources.list is what I got from the image download.

Comment: I'm out of ideas now. Wrong date settings would have been the most common error. Next step for me would be to use another update server for the security updates.

Comment: What would be another update server I can use?

Comment: `deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse` would be the server for Germany.

Comment: I tried two different servers none like my certificates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27321/discussion-between-knowhy-and-leb).